# Django global queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to have a global variable in my django app that stores resulting list of objects that I later use in some functions and I don't want to evaluate queryset more that once, i do it like this:

```
from app.models import StopWord

a = list(StopWord.objects.values_list('word', flat=True))
...

def some_func():
  ... (using a variable) ...
```

This seems ok to me but the problem is that syncdb and test command throw an exception:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'app_stopword' doesn't exist")
```

I don't know how to get rid of this, may be I am on a wrong way?

Comment: Is your app listed in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't initialize queries in a global scope. Bind `None` to the name, then write a function that first checks if the value is `None` and if so generates the data, and then returns the value.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the app that StopWord is a part of is either not in your installed apps setting, or you haven't run syncdb to generate the table.

Storing a 'global value' can be simulated by using the [django cache framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/).

```
# there is more to it then this - read the documentation
# settings.py needs to be configured.

from django.core.cache import cache

class StopWord(models.Model):
    ... # field definitions

    @classmethod
    def get_all_words(cls):
        key = 'StopWord.AllCachedWords.Key'
        words = cache.get(key)
        if words is None:
            words = list(StopWord.objects.values_list('word', flat=True))
            cache.set(key, words)
        return words

#elsewhere
from app.models import StopWord

for word in StopWord.get_all_words():
    # do something
```

The above also handles a sort of cache invalidation. Your settings should set a default timeout, or you can set your own timeout as a 3rd parameter to `cache.set()`. This ensures that while you avoid most database calls, the cache will be refreshed every so often so new stopwords can be used without restarting the application.