# DJANGO - Default filter in model

Tags: django, filter, model

I have 3 models :

```
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.TextField()

class Company(models.Model):
name = models.TextField()
users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User')

class Sales(models.Model):
product= models.ForeignKey(Product)
company= models.ForeignKey(Company)
seller = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

My goal is to display the list of all products sold by the company of request.user so in my views I do :

```
 Enterprise= Company.objects.filter(users=request.user)[0]
 Products_sold = Sales.objects.filter(company=Enterprise)
```

But since I have a lot of views I'm wondering if there is a way to it directly in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user should have `company_set`:

```
Products_sold = Sales.objects.filter(request.user.company_set.all()[0])
```

Comment: Is it possible to automate this in model of make a global queryset? I would like to avoid to write this in every single view

Comment: This is bad practice, but you can go for this. You can add method get_user_sales() like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513600/django-global-queryset